# parallel processing with R Package "ranger" in **Windows**

Tags: r, windows

I am trying to do parallel processing with R Package "ranger" in **Windows** environment.  I am having no luck.

In the past, I have done the following to do parallel processing with the R randomForest package with say data "train" and assuming your chip has 8 cores:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
library(randomForest)
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(8, type="SOCK"))
system.time( {rf = foreach(ntree = rep(125, 8), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% randomForest(y ~ ., data = train, ntree = ntree)} )
```

Basically the code above creates 125 trees in 8 separate cores and then combines the results into one single random forest object by the "combine" command that comes with the randomForest package.

However, the ranger package does not have a combine command and all my attempts to do parallel processing in **Windows** has not work.

The documentation (and the relevant publication) for ranger does not say how to do parallel processing in windows.

Any ideas how this can be done using ranger and **Windows** environment?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Windows environment you can use the "doParallel" package for enabling parallel processing, altought not all packages support parallel processing, you can try something like this but with your dessired parameters for the `ranger::csrf` function.

```
library(doParallel)
library(ranger)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
rf <- csrf(y ~ ., training_data = train,  test_data = test,
           params1 = list(num.trees = 125, mtry = 4), 
           params2 = list(num.trees = 5)
           )
stopCluster(cl)
```